# Dynamic table length adjustment in a Shiny App - R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to adjust the length of my amortization fund table. The problem is when I run for the first time the app and its formulas (such as 20 periods for the calculation), in the next run when I need to run 10 periods, the formula overwrites the calculation, keeping the values previously calculated.

The Shiny code its this:

```
#ui.r

library(shiny)

  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Fondo de Amortización"),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(numericInput(inputId = 'M',label = 'Monto',value = 2400000),
                     numericInput(inputId = 'n',label = 'Período',value = 20),
                     numericInput(inputId = 'i',label = 'Interés',value = 3.7)),

        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('x')))

    ))

#server.r

library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

  options(digits = 7)
  options(scipen = 999)

  IR <<- numeric();CA <<- numeric();SF <<- numeric()

  f.amort <- function(M,i,n) { 

    R <<- M*i/(((1 + i)**n)-1)
    IR[1] <<- 0
    IR[2] <<- R*i
    CA[1] <<- R
    SF[1] <<- R

    for (k in 1:(n-1)) {  

      CA[k+1] <<- R + IR[k+1]
      SF[k+1] <<- SF[k] + CA[k+1]

      if (k < n-1){
        IR[k+2] <<- SF[k+1]*i  
      }
    }
  }

  output$x <- renderTable({
    f.amort(input$M, input$i/100, input$n)
    tabla <- rbind((cbind("Rent" = c(R, recursive=TRUE), 
                          (cbind("I" = IR, "Acumulado" = CA,
                                           "BaC" = SF)))),
                   c(R*input$n,sum(IR),
                       sum(CA),000))
  })
})
```

I understand the calculation for the generation of the table, but at the moment of reproducing it dynamically in Shiny, I can not make its length adjust to the number of periods.

Here is the link when I got the idea of the app:
https://github.com/pakinja/-Financial-Mathematics-in-R/blob/master/AmortizationFund.r#L40

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using global variables in your shiny app is a bad idea since the global variables are shared among sessions. You should use `reactiveValues` instead.

Nonetheless, the problem with your code is that you need to reset all your variable in your function so that your length adjust with the number of period. Some thing like this:

```
f.amort <- function(M,i,n) { 

    R <<- M*i/(((1 + i)**n)-1)
    #Reset you variables
    IR <<- numeric();CA <<- numeric();SF <<- numeric()

    IR[1] <<- 0
    IR[2] <<- R*i
    CA[1] <<- R
    SF[1] <<- R

    for (k in 1:(n-1)) {  

      CA[k+1] <<- R + IR[k+1]
      SF[k+1] <<- SF[k] + CA[k+1]

      if (k < n-1){
        IR[k+2] <<- SF[k+1]*i  
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, defining the function outside the server would be a good idea, instead of cluttering the server with so many function.